# why string.split is not work with first space

Tags: javascript

```js
const str="w-full    from-[#b4abe3]  to-[hsl( 252, 100%, 96%)]"

console.log(str.split(/\s+/))
```

I have already tried, but unfortunately it outputs `'w-full' 'from-[#b4abe3]' 'to-[hsl(' '252,' '100%,' '96%)]'`.

I want the output to be
`"w-full" "from-[#b4abe3]" "to-[hsl( 252, 100%, 96%)]"`.

How can I split `str` correctly?

Comment: output is reasonable because you split string with key of 1 space or more because between `to-[hsl(` and `256` there is 1 space so they are also split

Comment: and i think you are using a css framework something like `unocss` i think that is not valid syntax

Comment: perhaps try `/\s\s+/`? since you want to split on 2 or more spaces

Answer (score 3):

The `+` quantifier matches one or more spaces.
Since you need to match two or more, use this quantifier: `{2,}`

```js
const str="w-full    from-[#b4abe3]  to-[hsl( 252, 100%, 96%)]"
console.log(str.split(/\s{2,}/))
// ['w-full', 'from-[#b4abe3]', 'to-[hsl( 252, 100%, 96%)]']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expression like the following:

```
(?<![,\(])\s+
```

Here the first part uses a negative look behind `(?<![,\(])`, which simply means, "match the space except if it's preceded by a comma or a parenthesis.

You can see it working here:

https://regex101.com/r/nPJDhe/1

Comment: Nice. work well.

Answer (score 0):

A reliable splitting (regardless of the number of encountered whitespace characters) can be done with the following regular expression:

```js
const str="w-full from-[#b4abe3]  to-[hsl( 252, 100%,   96%)]  [something  (else)]";

console.log(str.split(/(?<!\[[^\]]*)\s+(?![^[]\])/))
```

I generally find regular expressions hard to read and, for that reason,  usually only trust the ones I have written myself. But, in case, you want to give mine a try: here is an explanation:

The regular expression is made up of these parts:

- the "negative lookbehind" `(?<!\[[^\]]*)` asserting that no pattern of `[` followed by zero or more non-`]` characters precedes the ...
- one ore more whitespace characters `\s+`
- and, finally, the "negative lookahead" `(?![^[]\])` asserting that the whitespace is *not* followed by a pattern of zero or more non-`[` characters and a concluding `]` character.

The combination of negative lookbehind and lookahead patterns will avoid substrings contained in square brackets (like: `[a b  c]`) to be split.

Comment: Nice. work well.

Answer (score -1):

the first `whitespace` character in your input string is not a `regular space` character or may can't be recognized as a `regular space` character, but a `non-breaking space` character, that's all because you didn't enable the regular expression engine, you should put `u` letter at the end of your regEx because `u` flag is used to enable Unicode mode for the regular expression engine, so your regEx should work fine and match any `whitespace` character, including `non-breaking space` characters.

here's an example of what I said above:

```
const str = "w-full    from-[#b4abe3]  to-[hsl( 252, 100%, 96%)]";
console.log(str.split(/\s+/u)); // Output: ["w-full", "from-[#b4abe3]", "to-[hsl(", "252,", "100%,", "96%)]"]
```

Comment: Nope, this is wrong _and_ it misses the point of the question.